# Not able to retrieve variable in template in Django ajax call

Tags: django, ajax

I am trying retrieve counter value passed from view in the html template .It is coming as None, however in the view print and in ajax success log value it is coming correct.

JS ajax func

```
           $(".pos").click(function(){
            counter=counter+1;
            $(".add").html('add counter '+counter);
            $.ajax(
                { url :'page',
                  type :'get' ,
                 
                  data:{
                    quantity: counter
                   },
                    
                success:function(response){
                  console.log(response);
                }

                   
                   

                }
            );
```

My view

```
def page(request):
    counter=request.GET.get('quantity')
    print(counter) ## this is printing fine
    return render(request,'page.html',{'counter':counter})
```

html template

```
<body>
    {{counter}}
    <button class="btn neg" name="neg-btn">-</button>
    <button class="btn add" name="add-btn" >add to box</button>
    <button class="btn pos" id="test" name="pos-btn">+</button>
</body>
```

getting this counter as None

Comment: Your view returns  `HTML`,  In your `success` function you should then probably replace the old html with the new one from the response./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would have two views, one to render the template and another for your ajax request. This helps to keep your code more organized and have functions do exactly one task as most of the its described in its naming.

One important thing that is happening in your view, is that you are returning the HTML generated by the render API and not the counter value. Of course, there are many ways to do this correctly, but here is one possible solution:

page.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block content %}
<body>
    <div id="counter">
        {{counter}}
    </div>
    
    <button class="btn neg" id="neg" name="neg-btn">-</button>
    <button class="btn add" id="add" name="add-btn" >add to box</button>
    <button class="btn pos" id="pos" name="pos-btn">+</button>
</body>
{% endblock content %}

{% block script %}
<script>
    let counter = parseInt("{{counter}}");
    let page_url = "{% url 'core:page' %}";
    console.log(page_url)
    $( "#pos" ).click(function() {
        counter += 1;
        $( "#counter" ).replaceWith(`<div id="counter">${counter}</div>`);
    });
    $( "#neg" ).click(function() {
        counter -= 1;
        $( "#counter" ).replaceWith(`<div id="counter">${counter}</div>`);
    });
    $( "#add" ).click(function() {
        $.ajax({ 
                    url :page_url,
                    type :'post' ,
                    data:
                    {
                        counter: counter,
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    },                    
                    success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    }
                });
    });
</script>
{% endblock script %}
```

views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def page(request):
    counter = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        counter = int(request.POST.get('counter'))
        print(counter)
        return JsonResponse({'counter': counter})
    
    return render(request,'page.html',{'counter':counter})
```

Comment: Yes this solution can be used but in original code when I hard code counter to random number , it is showing correct in page.html , None coming only when context passed to view render function.Any idea why that can be.

Comment: Because `counter=request.GET.get('quantity')` does not exist when you first load the page (it is None). On the other hand when you hardcode it then `counter` has an inital value.